# Как переименовать имя пакета в eclipse

Tags: android

У меня одну игру забанили в Google Play за то, что я использовал похожее название с другой игрой. Можно ли как-то просто переименовать имя пакета, а не заново создавать проект? Программа создавалась в libGDX, т.е. игра состоит из 2х папок проект и проект-android

Comment: Переименовать можно, но есть шанс(90%), что гугл потом просто забанит аккаунт, как это произошло со мной

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какое имя пакетов Java у вас в приложении, Google абсолютно без разницы. Все что ему интересно, это `package` в манифесте. Его и переименовывайте, это просто текстовый атрибут в XML файле.

Comment: Если вам забанили приложение, забанят и рекламу в AdMob для него. Поэтому в AdMob лучше новое приложение зарегистрировать снова.

Comment: Нет, думаю все проще, они получают отчет кого забанили в GP и банят у себя. Основание: нарушение правил Google Play.